# C++ Adding elements to an Array of Pointers to a Struct Issue

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, struct

So I have a Struct called Person:

```cpp
struct Person {
    char *name;
    int initialMoney;
    int currentMoney;
};
```

I have made it so my main() reads a file called gift1.in containing:

```
5
dave
laura
owen
vick
amr
```

And a little bit more. What is important are these lines.
The first line represents how many people there are, then the rest are the people's names.
As you may have guessed, these names will become the `char *name` in the structs for Person.

Now for the problem:

```cpp
int main ()
{
    struct Person *peopleArray[MAXFRIENDSNUM];
    int index = 0;
    int maxIndex = 0;

    std::ofstream fout ("gift1.out");
    std::ifstream fin ("gift1.in");

    // Obtain max number of names!
    fin >> maxIndex;

    // Create a person for every name...
    for (index = 0; maxIndex != index; index++) {
            char newName[MAXNAMECHAR+1];
            fin >> newName;
            std::cout << "Inserting " << index << ": " <<newName << std::endl;
            makePerson(peopleArray, index, newName);
    }

    std::cout << "Checking if the proper person's name is there: \n";
    // Check to see if the person's name is being read correctly
    for (index = 0; maxIndex != index; index++) {
            std::cout << "Reading " << index <<  ":" << peopleArray[index]->name << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "Changing a single element of an array: \n";
    peopleArray[1]->name = (char *)"John";

    for (index = 0; maxIndex != index; index++) {
            std::cout << "Reading " << index <<  ":" << peopleArray[index]->name << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
 }

void makePerson(Person *peopleArray[], int insertIndex, char *name) 
{
    peopleArray[insertIndex] = (Person *)malloc(sizeof(peopleArray[insertIndex]));
    peopleArray[insertIndex]->name = name;
    peopleArray[insertIndex]->initialMoney = 0;
    peopleArray[insertIndex]->currentMoney = 0;
    peopleArray[insertIndex] = peopleArray[insertIndex];
}
```

From my understanding, each element in `peopleArray[]` has a pointer to a Struct Person. However, since I create the Struct in another scope, I have to allocate it (hence the use of malloc()).

So my understanding is that I should get:

```
Inserting 0: dave
Inserting 1: laura
Inserting 2: owen
Inserting 3: vick
Inserting 4: amr
Checking if the proper person's name is there: 
Reading 0:dave
Reading 1:laura
Reading 2:owen
Reading 3:vick
Reading 4:amr
Changing a single element of an array: 
Reading 0:dave
Reading 1:John
Reading 2:owen
Reading 3:vick
Reading 4:amr
```

However, from running the actual C++ script I get:

```
Inserting 0: dave
Inserting 1: laura
Inserting 2: owen
Inserting 3: vick
Inserting 4: amr
Checking if the proper person's name is there: 
Reading 0:amr
Reading 1:amr
Reading 2:amr
Reading 3:amr
Reading 4:amr
Changing a single element of an array: 
Reading 0:amr
Reading 1:John
Reading 2:amr
Reading 3:amr
Reading 4:amr
```

Which makes it seem like I am getting complete duplicates from using malloc() rather than allocating new memory.

So my question is:
Why does this happen? What is going on inside memory to cause this

What can I do to fix this? I know for sure an alternative is to just make an array of structs, but I'm curious to see what a solution could be to keep using an array of pointers to structs.

Disclaimer: Sorry if my C++ does not look much like C++! I've been using more C and I'm slowly making the transition, so my C++ looks a lot like C, (use of char *name instead of string).

Additonal hardware information (if that is the issue): I am using clang++ from macports on a Mac OS X Mavericks (newest version)

Comment: The biggest help to you is going to be to switch all of the `char *` to `std::string` and all of the `arrays` to `std::vector`...

Comment: You're writing in C++ so you should prefer `new` to `malloc`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Create a person for every name...
for (index = 0; maxIndex != index; index++) {
        char newName[MAXNAMECHAR+1];
```

Here you allocate memory on the stack to store a name. You haven't told the compiler that there needs to be one of these per loop, so either you will allocate/free the stack space each iteration or your compiler will treat it as this:

```
char newName[MAXNAMECHAR+1];
for (index ... ) {
    ...
```

Each name you read goes into this variable, which is very likely at the same location in memory/the stack. You pass the address of this memory to your create function:

```
       makePerson(peopleArray, index, newName);
```

which then stores that address in your Person objects. So they all point to the same address - a temporary location on the stack.

You should consider either making the entry in `Person` a `std::string` or making `name` copy the string it is being passed.

```
struct Person {
    std::string name;
    int initialMoney;
    int currentMoney;

    Person(const char* name_) : initialMoney(0), currentMoney(0) {}
};
```

and `makePerson` becomes

```
void makePerson(Person *peopleArray[], int insertIndex, char *name) 
{
    peopleArray[insertIndex] = new Person(name);
}
```

Remember, though, you will need to `delete` these objects (just as you should have been `free`ing them before) when you are done with them, on consider `std::unique_ptr` http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr

Here is a C++ implementation:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::vector;
using std::string;

struct Person {
    string m_name;
    int    m_initialMoney;
    int    m_currentMoney;

    Person(const std::string& name_, int money_=0)
        : m_name(name_)
        , m_initialMoney(0), m_currentMoney(0)
        {}
};

int main ()
{
    vector<Person> people;

    // Obtain max number of names!
    size_t maxIndex = 0;
    cin >> maxIndex;
    if (maxIndex <= 0) {
        cout << "Nothing to do.\n";
        return 1;
    }

    // Create a person for every name...
    for (size_t index = 0; maxIndex != index; index++) {
            std::string newName;
            cin >> newName;
            cout << "Inserting " << people.size() << ": " << newName << std::endl;
            people.emplace_back(newName);
    }

    // Check to see if the person's name is being read correctly
    cout << "Checking if the proper person's name is there: \n";
    for (auto& person : people) {
            cout << "Reading " << person.m_name << std::endl;
    }

    cout << "Changing a single element of an array: \n";
    people[1].m_name = "John";

    for (auto& person : people) {
            cout << "Reading " << person.m_name << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

see http://ideone.com/jjfPda

Comment: Really thorough and I loved it, thanks for pointing me towards proper C++ libraries to use as well as a solution to my current code also!

Answer (score 0):

You assign Person.name the same pointer over and over again which is why they all just "take" the changes you do on the original adress.

To alter this behaviour you have to create a new instance for each entry (by using strcpy for example)
after that you get your expected behaviour.

---

Also here you go with some saver way of doing it by using std::string and std::vector:
http://pastebin.com/Ftt5FKeX

Answer (score 0):

As @Ben stated, bite the bullet and use only C++ conventions.  Your problem is here with your delcaration of newName.  you are declaring it on the stack, locally in scope to the for loop, and it most likely has the same address every time.  So the last entry in your file you read, "amr" is then assigned to that address.  You then copy that pointer arount in makePerson, and assign to the char *name element in that struct.

```
for (index = 0; maxIndex != index; index++) {
         char newName[MAXNAMECHAR+1];
        makePerson(peopleArray, index, newName);
}
```

You can fix that (badly) by allocating the memory for the name:

```
char * newName = new char[MAXNAMECHAR+1];
```

But then you also have to clean-up after yourself and delete the memory.  Start using "real" C++, and avoid all this malloc garbage.